# How to enter Qt Context Help mode programmatically?

Tags: qt

When the context help button "?" on a QDialog is clicked it enters help mode. Is there a way to switch to that mode programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode you are referring to is called "What's this" mode. According to the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwhatsthis.html) you can switch between this and normal modes, as described:

> You can enter "What's This?" mode programmatically with
>   enterWhatsThisMode(), check the mode with inWhatsThisMode(), and
>   return to normal mode with leaveWhatsThisMode().

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is "What's this" mode.